# GNU Scientific Library, Power function efficiency

Tags: c

I was going through GSL library. I am pasting the function they used for finding the power of a double number.

```
double gsl_pow_int(double x, int n)
{
  double value = 1.0;

  if(n < 0) {
    x = 1.0/x;
    n = -n;
  }

  /* repeated squaring method 
   * returns 0.0^0 = 1.0, so continuous in x
   */
  do {
     if(n & 1) value *= x;  /* for n odd */
     n >>= 1;
     x *= x;
  } while (n);

  return value;
}
```

But wouldn't it be more efficient if they use?

```
double gsl_pow_int(double x, int n)
    {
      double value = 1.0;

      if(n < 0) {
        x = 1.0/x;
        n = -n;
      }

      /* repeated squaring method 
       * returns 0.0^0 = 1.0, so continuous in x
       */
      do{
        if(--n)value*=x;
    }while(n);
    return value;
 }
```

Comment: Possibly more efficient, probably not. You need to profile. In terms of complexity, the first snippet is better (**O(log n)** instead of **O(n)**).

Comment: This question does not include any problems. You should post this kind of questions to [Codereview](https://codereview.com)

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the `/* repeated squaring method ...*/` comment in the original.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Could you explain in more detail. I want to know why their method is more efficient.

Comment: I suggest tracing through the steps of the algorithm for a particular example (say `x = 1.5, n = 300`) in both cases.  You'll find that their algorithm ends up doing many fewer multiplications.

Comment: @InQusitive: [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Thanks, Understood. I missed the point of the /* repeated squaring method ...*/ comment in the original.:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't even properly handle negative powers! How can you claim that your code is optimised.

> Also,next,just decreasing space from your program doesn't make your
>   code more-optimised.Their code has got more readability and more
>   proper indentation than yours!!! Their code is proper for negative
>   powers too and much more optimised!

Also,next, bitwise logical operations like `&` and right shifting `>>` is considered more efficient than multiplying as what you have done.

Comment: Sorry, I was considering only the do while part, Edited :)

Comment: @InQusitive: That doesn't change the answer. Do you believe, they couldn't think of your suggested solution? Probably they picked up their solution, because it's faster…